# Why paralel stream could provide not full list of elements

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap, java-stream

I'm converting string array to hashmap using stream.

```
    String[] arguments= new String[]{"-a","1","-b","2","-c","3","-d","4","-e","5"};
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
            .limit(arguments.length / 2)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(i -> params.put(arguments[i], arguments[i + 1]));
    System.out.println(params.size());
```

It shows 5, but sometimes 4.

Could you explain, please, what could be the reason of different results?

Comment: *"I'm converting string array to hashmap **using stream**"* Why? Use a normal `for` loop. It's faster, simpler, clearer, and it works!

Comment: Step 1: learning to solve a problem without `forEach`. Step 2: recognizing that a parallel stream doesn’t pay off for such a trivial task (especially not with the parallel-unfriendly `iterate(…).limit(…)` combo). If you want an efficient solution, you may use `HashMap<String, String> params = IntStream.range(0, arguments.length/2).map(i -> i*2) .collect(HashMap::new, (m,i) -> m.put(arguments[i], arguments[i+1]), Map::putAll);` that would work in parallel, but there’s still no benefit in parallel processing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking a fundamental stream property - no side-effects. And your stream has a side-effect via `forEach`. In simpler words you put elements from multiple threads into a non-thread-safe collection `HashMap`.

The correct way to do it, would be to collect that via:

```
String[] arguments = new String[] { "-a", "1", "-b", "2", "-c", "3", "-d", "4", "-e", "5" };
    Map<String, String> map = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
            .limit(arguments.length / 2)
            .parallel()
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> arguments[i], i -> arguments[i + 1]));

    System.out.println(map); // {-a=1, -b=2, -c=3, -d=4, -e=5}
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with parallel streams, the operations must be *stateless* otherwise due to thread scheduling differences, you'll get non-deterministic results.

This line:

```
.forEach(i -> params.put(arguments[i], arguments[i + 1]));
```

is the cause of the different results at each execution.

The solution to your problem is to utilize the `collect` reduction operation and avoid `forEach`.

You can find more information about *stateless* behaviors and *Side-effects* within the **[JAVA Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)**.